# Apache won't Start in Xampp

Tags: apache, xampp

Trying to start Apache in the latest version of Xampp and I'm receiving an error. After going into error logs I got this

```
 `Installing Apache HTTP Server 2.x with
 DomainName    = example.com
 ServerName    = www.example.com
 ServerAdmin   = admin@example.com
 ServerPort    = 80
 ServerSslPort = 443
 ServerRoot    = c:/Apache24
Rewrote docs/conf/extra/httpd-autoindex.conf.in
 to c:/Apache24/conf/original/extra/httpd-autoindex.conf
Rewrote docs/conf/extra/httpd-default.conf.in
 to c:/Apache24/conf/original/extra/httpd-default.conf
Rewrote docs/conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf.in
 to c:/Apache24/conf/original/extra/httpd-ssl.conf
Rewrote docs/conf/extra/httpd-multilang-errordoc.conf.in
 to c:/Apache24/conf/original/extra/httpd-multilang-errordoc.conf
Rewrote docs/conf/extra/httpd-info.conf.in
 to c:/Apache24/conf/original/extra/httpd-info.conf
Rewrote docs/conf/extra/httpd-userdir.conf.in
 to c:/Apache24/conf/original/extra/httpd-userdir.conf
Rewrote docs/conf/extra/httpd-mpm.conf.in
 to c:/Apache24/conf/original/extra/httpd-mpm.conf
Rewrote docs/conf/httpd.conf.in
 to c:/Apache24/conf/original/httpd.conf
Rewrote docs/conf/extra/proxy-html.conf.in
 to c:/Apache24/conf/original/extra/proxy-html.conf
Rewrote docs/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf.in
 to c:/Apache24/conf/original/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
Rewrote docs/conf/extra/httpd-dav.conf.in
 to c:/Apache24/conf/original/extra/httpd-dav.conf
Rewrote docs/conf/extra/httpd-languages.conf.in
 to c:/Apache24/conf/original/extra/httpd-languages.conf
Rewrote docs/conf/extra/httpd-manual.conf.in
 to c:/Apache24/conf/original/extra/httpd-manual.conf
Duplicated c:/Apache24/conf/original/extra/httpd-autoindex.conf
 to c:/Apache24/conf/extra/httpd-autoindex.conf
Duplicated c:/Apache24/conf/original/extra/httpd-default.conf
 to c:/Apache24/conf/extra/httpd-default.conf
Duplicated c:/Apache24/conf/original/extra/httpd-ssl.conf
 to c:/Apache24/conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf
Duplicated c:/Apache24/conf/original/extra/httpd-multilang-errordoc.conf
 to c:/Apache24/conf/extra/httpd-multilang-errordoc.conf
Duplicated c:/Apache24/conf/original/extra/httpd-info.conf
 to c:/Apache24/conf/extra/httpd-info.conf
Duplicated c:/Apache24/conf/original/extra/httpd-userdir.conf
 to c:/Apache24/conf/extra/httpd-userdir.conf
Duplicated c:/Apache24/conf/original/extra/httpd-mpm.conf
 to c:/Apache24/conf/extra/httpd-mpm.conf
Duplicated c:/Apache24/conf/original/httpd.conf
 to c:/Apache24/conf/httpd.conf
Duplicated c:/Apache24/conf/original/magic
 to c:/Apache24/conf/magic
Duplicated c:/Apache24/conf/original/charset.conv
 to c:/Apache24/conf/charset.conv
Duplicated c:/Apache24/conf/original/extra/proxy-html.conf
 to c:/Apache24/conf/extra/proxy-html.conf
Duplicated c:/Apache24/conf/original/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
 to c:/Apache24/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
Duplicated c:/Apache24/conf/original/extra/httpd-dav.conf
 to c:/Apache24/conf/extra/httpd-dav.conf
Duplicated c:/Apache24/conf/original/mime.types
 to c:/Apache24/conf/mime.types
Duplicated c:/Apache24/conf/original/extra/httpd-languages.conf
 to c:/Apache24/conf/extra/httpd-languages.conf
Duplicated c:/Apache24/conf/original/extra/httpd-manual.conf
 to c:/Apache24/conf/extra/httpd-manual.conf
```

I checked to make sure nothing is running on port 80 or 443 and nothing was so I'm kind of drawing a blank here.

Not Sure why the error log is messed up either

Comment: have you installed apache before, second is your skype is on during installation.

Comment: Yes I have installed it before, and no I turned skype off after disabling it on port 443 and 80.

Comment: Your apache is not un install properly, so configuration and registry file shows conflict here. stop all process iis, skype, apache and then re install.

Comment: Very late but might be of use to future troubleshooters. You can uninstall apache as shown in this tutorial: http://www.ehow.com/how_7361546_uninstall-apache-windows.html